# Adding HorizontalScrollview to multiple layout

Tags: android, android-listview, horizontalscrollview

I want to create a custom list view.So i created a xml with list item and another xml for row item.For row items I have:
I have a Relative Layout.In which i added textview,Linear Layout.In the Linear Layout I added Horizontal Scrollview and in Horizontal Scrollview I added another Linear Layout with dynamic image views.

**The problem is that after i added horizontal scrollview i am not able to do onclick.There is no effect of click.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove first `LinearLayout` in which you have added a `HorizontalScrollView` as it is useless for `horizontalScrollView`.After removing that add

`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

to the

`RelativeLayout` of Row.xml .

This should work

Comment: But i am not getting on click on the images that i added